# Admob GDPR Consent Message doesn't show up on internal test?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, admob, gdprconsentform

I have a game made with Unity on Google Play and am using Admob to show ads. Since Admob demands to show users GDPR Consent Message at the start of the game I am trying to implement it.

I created the message on Admob and managed to show it on Unity Editor with this script;

```
public class GDPRScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    ConsentForm _consentForm;
    void Start()
    {
        var debugSettings = new ConsentDebugSettings
        {
            DebugGeography = DebugGeography.EEA,
            TestDeviceHashedIds = new List<string>
            {
                "I am using the advertising ID of my phone here."
            }
        };
 
        ConsentRequestParameters request = new ConsentRequestParameters
        {
            TagForUnderAgeOfConsent = false,
            ConsentDebugSettings = debugSettings,
        };
 
        ConsentInformation.Update(request, OnConsentInfoUpdated);
    }
 
    void OnConsentInfoUpdated(FormError error)
    {
        if (error != null)
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.LogError(error);
            return;
        }
 
        if (ConsentInformation.IsConsentFormAvailable())
        {
            LoadConsentForm();
        }
    }
 
    void LoadConsentForm()
    {
        ConsentForm.Load(OnLoadConsentForm);
    }
 
    void OnLoadConsentForm(ConsentForm consentForm, FormError error)
    {
        if (error != null)
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.LogError(error);
            return;
        }
 
        _consentForm = consentForm;
 
        if (ConsentInformation.ConsentStatus == ConsentStatus.Required)
        {
            _consentForm.Show(OnShowForm);
        }
    }
 
 
    void OnShowForm(FormError error)
    {
        if (error != null)
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.LogError(error);
            return;
        }
 
        LoadConsentForm();
    }
}
```

The message works fine on the editor and APK builds on my phone but doesn't show up on the internal test. I checked with Logcat and didn't see any errors.

My guess is it doesn't even call "ConsentInformation.Update(request, OnConsentInfoUpdated);" because otherwise, I would see the debug errors. But since it is working on editor and apk this situation confuses me. I can't build a bundle with debug otherwise I can't create an internal test with it.

What can I do to solve this issue? I really appreciate any help you can provide.